# Schematic notes: Place capacitor as "close" to pins: Is this a necessary note? Is it a significant point?

Tags: capacitor, shielding, smoothing-capacitor

**Background**

I am building a ATMega4809 board that allows the board to be programmed using the Arduino IDE.
While examining the following schematic I noticed that where the caps are placed the author included a note on each.

[image: ATMega4809 programmer]

Here's a close up of the note:
[image: as close to pin as possible]

**Question: Close To Pins?**

My question is, "Is this a mis-understanding by the author, or is it actually necessary that the capacitor be placed very "close" to the pins which they are attempting to shield?

Close seems a bit subjective.  Should you solder them to the pins?  Should they be in the breadboard holes exactly next to the pins.  Do you just insure that their is nothing (no other component) "between" the cap and the pins?

Does this really matter -- have significance?

In contrast, I can imagine if they were "far" there could be a difference possibly. But if they're all connected it seems as if it wouldn't matter.

I've (attempted) to use capacitors like this in the past and I'm wondering if I should consider this as I use them in the future.

Comment: A lot of times what is done is to place a cap or caps between VDD and ground.  So for every VDD pin of the device you place a cap between that pin and ground.  Is there a place for the caps on the PCB?  You place then as close as possible to the part like the note says (doing your best).  Place them in the breadboard holes next to the part. This is for decoupling and energy storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitors don't "shield."

Capacitors are placed on the power supply pins to absorb noise coming in from the power supply and to supply short bursts of high current when the processor switches states.

Long wires act as inductors.  That reduces the effectiveness of the capacitors.

1. The author really meant for you to place the capacitors as stated in the comments in the schematic.
2. "Close" means as close as phyically possible with the smallest inductance conenctions possible.  Short, wide traces between the capacitor and the pins.  Ideally, you'd use a surface mount capacitor and snuggle it right up beside the pins.
3. This not an ideal circuit for use on a wireless breadboard - getting the oscillator to run correctly will be painful.
4. Capacitors placed just anywhere because they are all connected together is a bad plan.  Put each capacitor where the schematic tells you.

Comment: Thanks very much for the specific numbered points.  This is very good and extremely helpful to my (hobbyist) understanding.  Also thanks for explaining that these are not "shielding". Really great, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The point is to avoid excessive inductance between the capacitor and the chip it's decoupling. If you have long PCB traces between them, that's an impedance that prevents the capacitor from supplying current as quickly as it could otherwise, limiting how fast of a transient it can respond to. In turn, that limits the maximum speed the chip it's decoupling can run at, whether that be frequency in a CPU or output pulse characteristics in a gate driver, or whatever else you're using.

Remember that wires aren't just wires, they always have parasitic elements involved. At high speeds, the inductance and capacitance of PCB traces mandates careful layout design, and that's what these notes are intended to help with--they're telling you that this is a part of the circuit that's particularly sensitive to layout. In extreme cases, manufacturers will even give you complete layout recommendations, showing exactly where you should position capacitors and resistors and copper traces to ensure their chip works as specified.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This really helps me in my (hobbyist) understanding. I appreciate you explaining this in another way and really focusing on the points about wires aren't just wires.  Fantastic help.

Answer (score 1):

It matters.  They should be placed as close as possible to the pins while maintaining all the design rules of the PCB fab and assembly.  They should all have good low-impedance connections to ground as well.

This is to keep the parasitic inductance (and even resistance) to a minimum.  These "bypass" or "decoupling" caps provide a local energy reservoir for high current transients.  If these transients had to come from far away, the series inductance and resistance would cause a dip and ringing in the supply, which can cause erratic operation or failure to operate at all.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This improves my (hobbyist) understanding as I move forward. (And I've seen these bypass / coupling caps before and never seen that message.  Interesting.